# setInterval - ajax with string attached (GET)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I need help figuring out how i can setInterval while keeping a "str" to the function.

The client chooses an option, and the function "GET"'s the selected option.. But when it refreshes in setInterval, it looses the string.. How can i do this?

I have tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function countrystats(str)
  {
  if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("countrystats").innerHTML="";

  return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  document.getElementById("countrystats").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","countrystats.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

 setInterval(countrystats, 5000);


  }
  </script>
```

Hopefully you can help me sort out this mess :-)

I am aware that this can be done with some jQuery, but i cat seem to get that to work. Maybe those two things are related, i dont know :-)

Here is how the function countrystats gets its input:

```
script type="text/javascript">
$("#countrystats_menu > li > a").click(function (ev) {
  var str = $(this).html();
  countrystats(str);

  $('#country_span').html(str);
  });


  </script>
```

EDIT/Solution:

It seems that the problem was, when doing setInterval, it looses the str attached, this code is however preserving it.

```
setTimeout((function(strPriorToTimeout)
{//IIFE's scope preserves state of str variable
    return function()
    {
        countrystats(strPriorToTimeout);
    };
})(str),5000);
```

Comment: `setInterval(countrystats(str), 5000);`

Comment: setInterval(countrystats, 5000); move this outside the function

Comment: why are you using raw ajax with jQuery?

Comment: @ArunPJohny , When you see it , just know that some one is thinking that jQuery is a language

Comment: It doesn't seem to run if i do the setInterval with (str) attached, like this: setInterval(countrystats(str), 5000);

and if i put it outside the function, it still returns empty :(

Comment: @ArunPJohny it was the solution i found at the time, i'm sadly not that experienced yet.. Im trying though :-)

Which solution would you prefer?

Comment: @nielskildsgaard I've updated an answer check it and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument `str` goes out of scope at the end, the interval simply calls the function *without* passing any value to `str`. As some comments suggest, `countrystats(str)` would *appear* to do the trick, but it doesn't, here's why:

```
setInterval(countrystats(str), 500);
```

This line contains multiple expressions that *will* be evaluated/resolved to some value, like `countrystats(str)`, which is a direct call to a function. The function, then, will be called prior to the interval being set. 
The quickest solution is creating an anonymous function, and call the function from within:

```
setInterval(function()
{
    countrystats(str);
},5000);
```

You can even play it *extra* safe, by creating a closure, actually passing the intended value of `str` to the interval function. This is optional, and might look a bit confusing (and messy):

```
setInterval((function(strPriorToTimeout)
{//IIFE's scope preserves state of str variable
    return function()
    {
        countrystats(strPriorToTimeout);
    };
})(str),5000);
```

There is just one thing that's bothering me about your code: you're using `setInterval`, which repeats the same function call every X ms. If you only need to call a function once, it might be better using `setTimeout`.
Another thing is: `setInterval` returns the interval's id, so you can stop the constant function calls if needed. You don't seem to be assigning that ID anywhere, so your code will keep on running, unless you're brute-forcing the `clearInterval` calls. Perhaps consider assigning the return value of `setInterval` to some variable you can access.
If you don't the only way of clearing intervals AFAIK would be:

```
for (var i=0;i<Number.MAX_VALUE;i++)
{
    clearInterval(i);
}
```

Now that's just terrible, isn't it?

In light of the comments, I thought I'd do well adding some info on webworkers here. From what I gather the OP wants to acchieve, I recommended using webworkers as much as possible. A basic setup here could be:

```
//client.js
var worker = new Worker('dashWorker.js');//worker script
//to kick off the worker: 
function countrystats(str)
{
    str = str || document.getElementById('countrystats').innerHTML;//get str value
    worker.postMessage(str);//that's it, the worker takes care of everything else
}
worker.onmessage = function(response)
{
    document.getElementById('countrystats').innerHTML = response.response;//cf worker code
    return countrystats(response.str);//choose when to call the countrystats function again, as soon as the worker responded... easy!
};

//the worker:
self.onmessage = function(e)
{//you could add a way of stopping the constant updates, by posting a 'stopDash' or something...
    //do ajax call using e.data --> this is the string anyhow
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(response)
    {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
        {
            self.postMessage({str: e.data, 
                              response: response.responseText});
        }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', 'countrystats.php?q=' + e.data,true);
    xhr.send();
};
```

Of course, this code is far from *"clean"*: it could do with some performance tweaks (like not querying the DOM all the time), but the basic principal stands... 
A couple of important links for you here:

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers)
[John Resig's blog post on workers](http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/)
[A step-by-step introduction to webworkers](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-started-with-web-workers/)

Comment: I played extra safe, and ill be damned, it worked like a charm :-)
And thank you for cutting it out for me.. It helped!

Comment: @nielskildsgaard: I forgot to mention this, but the not-so-safe-way just references `str`, so if the function gets called a second time while the interval is running, values might change. That's why the additional IIFE can be useful. It does, at least provide a more predictable result. Also do take my comments on `setTimeout`/`setInterval` into consideration. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks mate, although i want it to keep running. Im creating a dashboard with multiple SQL/php connection, so to keep it "dynamic", this seems to be the only solution im left with.

e.g. New orders coming in, i would want a frequent call to a server to check if there are any new orders.

Comment: Maybe the solution i need is actually a refresh button?!

It makes sense for some of my widgets/boxes. Instead of constantly running some code.

Comment: @nielskildsgaard: I'd google `webworkers` if I were you... this is exactly the kind of thing they were _designed_ to do. Let your worker communicate with the server, and just add an event listener in your main JS script...

Comment: That looks excactly like the code i should use, thank you :) that'll keep me occupied for a while.. hehe

Comment: @nielskildsgaard: Added a small snippet to get you started with workers, and a couple of links that might prove useful to you...

Comment: If i had any points to hand out, i'd throw them at you :-) thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you are calling  setInterval(countrystats, 5000);  in the same function. you can do with jquery also

```
url='countrystats.php?q='+str;
```

ajax calll

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
  $('#countrystats').html(data);

});
```

once the get finishes. you can call `setInterval(countrystats, 5000);` for refreshing the content.

Comment: I'm afraid i'm not quite following..

Is my function countrystats(str) supposed to be replaced with

´$.get(url, function(data) {
  $('#countrystats').html(data);

});´

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your code with jQuery. I've used [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the remote html to the start element.

And whenever a new item is clicked you need to create the previous interval, otherwise multiple request threads will be running

```
function countrystats(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        $('#countrystats').empty();
        return;
    }

    $('#countrystats').load('countrystats.php?q=' + str)

}

var interval;
$("#countrystats_menu > li > a").click(function(ev) {
    if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    var str = $(this).html();

    countrystats(str);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
                countrystats(str);
            }, 5000);

    $('#country_span').html(str);
});
```